# Which is better for use Theano on Linux or Windows?

Tags: theano

Which is better for use Theano on Linux or Windows? I want to try some deep learning methods by Theano.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine on both, but I find better support for CUDA and much it is easier to install the scientific Python stack on Linux (usually Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

I use Theano on windows and once you use a package like enthought canopy or anaconda I find it easy to install and use. Although like a lot of this stuff on windows it is probably easier on Linux! :)